# blender does not show information

Tags: interface

I was following one tutorial and there the tutor selects some vertices and it was shown lower right (how many vertices etc.) corner of the interface. But in my Blender interface nothing pops up in lower right if I select anything!

I want to see how many vertices I have selected. How can I activate it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press right click on the status bar:

[image]

Alternatively, you can turn on statistics as an overlay:

[image]

[image]